# Creating a Group in Desire2Learn Valence

Tags: desire2learn

I am trying to use Valence to create a group.  Everything looks right (the orgunit and group category exist), but I'm getting a WebException indicating "not found".  My test program's output is below.  Can anyone confirm that the documentation for the uri and JSON blocks is correct and that the "create group" function does indeed work?

```
D:\d2lmgmt>Valence.exe function=create_orgunit_groupcategory_group requestor=hidden orgunitid=16800 groupcategoryid=2845
Uri:  "/d2l/api/lp/1.0/16800/groupcategories/2845/groups/", method:  "POST"
POST input:  "{"Name":"grouptest name","Code":"grouptestcode","Description":{"Text":"grouptest text","Html":"grouptest html"}}"
WebException:  Not found
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the input you are sending is "RichText" rather than "RichTextInput" which is a [slightly different structure](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/conventions.html#commonly-used-fields).

REQUEST:

```
POST https://valence.desire2learn.com/d2l/api/lp/1.0/7733/groupcategories/1879/groups/?x_b=TwULqrltMXvTE8utuLCN5O&x_a=L2Hd9WvDTcyiyu5n2AEgpg&x_d=NPSqMuaKFhpcE2TWRbvh-wK4I25tGdFPzUzqpolELKk&x_c=IQwjo0WycWje8IrhJuxqMC7U5BWOVVwwMFAZWp3a1ag&x_t=1343942454 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "Name": "Group 1",
    "Code": "Group 1 code",
    "Description": {
        "Content": "Group 1 description",
        "Type": "Text"
    }
}
```

RESPONSE:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 109
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Date: Thu, 02 Aug 2012 21:20:44 GMT

{"GroupId":7744,"Name":"Group 1","Description":{"Text":"Group 1 description","Html":""},"Enrollments":[4062]}
```